# Selenium ide and need to get a table count after searching for a record

Tags: selenium-ide

Hi I am using selenium ide and need to get a table count after searching for a record. An example of the page is [here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/table-sort-search-demo.html).

After entering the name I want to search for I want to count the matching result records. I used `getXpathCount` to count the records but it does not seem to increment the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in Selenium IDE-

```
storeXpathCount    |   //table[@id='example']/tbody/tr/td[contains(.//text(),'Edinburgh')]     |    myVarCount

echo  |   ${myVarCount}
```

Comment: After doing the search if I do the storeXpathCount the value is zero